# Jquery code not running in partial page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a jQuery script included in my MasterPage's `<head>` tags that runs whenever a link is pressed in the navbar. (I've made it trigger on any anchor tag.)

So I was thinking: since it triggers on any anchor tag it would also trigger on anchor tags that are in segment files (files that contain a little HTML and are inserted using AJAX) but it doesn't.
The only way to get it to work is to include the JavaScript file into all the segment pages.

example:
mainpage:

```
<br>
html
<br>
head<br> script src="script.js"/script<br>/head
<br>
body
div class="container"/div
```

All the partial html files are loaded into the container.
So one would think they also share the same `<head>` as the full page still contains that same header.
But the scripts don't work?

ps: to the unclear what i'm asking report: apparently some people understood me, thanks a lot to those who did :)

Comment: Are you using `.click()`? or `.on()`?

Comment: I am making this assumption not seeing your javascript, but the click event that you are attaching to the anchor tags is attaching when the page loads. Then you are loading in more stuff with ajax. Because those elements loaded by ajax don't exist, the click event cannot be attached to them.

Comment: @max what should i be using instead of click() to make it attach?

Comment: You could try using on like @ChristopheBiocca said

Comment: .on("click") doesn't work either :(

Comment: it does work on the main page but not on the AJAX pages

Comment: @g3mini: It will if you use the **delegate** version, not the **direct** one, as I show in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry you were right, i didn't use the on event correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to *delegate* the event to all current and future anchor elements using a particular version of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(function() { // dom-ready
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        // handle click
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you load content dynamically then events won´t be hooked. Use "on" event instead of "click".

It would be something like:

```
$( "a" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: Using .on("click") doesn't work either

Comment: Have a look at Cory snippet. It can depend on which version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: @AlfonsoMuñoz: Version *and* usage. `on()` works in a couple of different ways.

Comment: Cory's snippet works, idk who downvoted this one but i think this works on a different version indeed. Thanks for the help anyway :)